# add current time to chart xaxis

Tags: c#, charts, axis-labels

I have a simple problem, I do some measurements and show at chart with windowsforms, .net 4.
when I add this to chart also I need to add current time to xaxis. 
I found how to add time but when a new measurement comes all the old labels were changing to last measurement's time.
what should I add after this line?

```
chart1.Series["Example"].Points.Add(ms);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should state what chart class or framework you are using, WPF, Windows Forms, ASP.NET ?

Comment: You need to maintain old measurements either in your local list variable or in the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add xy point and it works fine.
Then can set the angle 90 to show time nicer at graph.

```
   chart1.Series["Example"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), ms);
   chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
```

Thanks.